# Heroku is switching my play framework 2 config file

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I have a Play! application which is on Heroku.

My config file is different between my local application and the same on Heroku. Especially for the URL of my MongoDB base.

On localhost my base address is 127.0.0.1 and on heroku it's on MongoHQ. So when I push my application to Heroku I modify my config file.

But some times, like this morning Heroku change the config file. I pushed my application correctly configured on Heroku this morning and everything worked until now.

When I watch the logs I see that Heroku changed my config and try to connect to my local MongoDB base.

Is someone knowing what ? I hope I'm clear :)

Thanks everybody !

Answer (score 0):

If there are differences in your application in different environments (e.g. local vs production), you should be using [assigning the values with environment variables](http://www.12factor.net/config). For Play apps, you can use environment variables in your `application.conf` file, like this:

```
`mongo.url=${MONGO_URL}`
```

Then, on Heroku you can set the environment variables with [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), like this (note, this may already be assigned for you by the add-on provider):

```
$ heroku config:add MONGO_URL=...
```

Locally, you can use [Foreman](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#developing-locally-with-foreman) to run your application with the environment variables stored in an `.env` file in your project root.

Comment: Thanks ! I chose an another method.